# Migrating to Spring data couchbase 4.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

My project was in spring boot version 2.2.1 (spring-data-couchbase version 2.2.1 and couchbase SDK 3.2.1) , we have to upgrade this project to Spring boot 2.4.1 (spring-data-couchbase version 2.4.1 and couchbase SDK 4.2.1) , a lot of things have changed from couchbase SDK 3.x to 4.x , which are captured in the document [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.migrating) ,

But still I could not find some of things or configuration and how to do them in the newer version ,

from the older project in version 2.2.1 ,

```
QueryServiceConfig queryServiceConfig =
        QueryServiceConfig.create(queryserviceMinEndpoint, queryserviceMaxEndpoint);
    return DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
        .queryServiceConfig(queryServiceConfig)
        .autoreleaseAfter(autoreleaseAfter)
        .build();
```

It seems in the newer version they have removed QueryServiceConfig and DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment classes , Does anyone know how to define these configs in the newer version ? I mean the `autoreleaseAfter` , queryservice `minEndpoints` and `maxEndpoints` , I tried creating them via application.yaml but doesnt work , Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 spring:
        couchbase:
          password: xyz
          username: admin
          bootstrap-hosts: 127.0.0.1
          bucket:
            name: xyz
            password: xyz
          env:
            endpoints:
              queryserivce:
                max-endpoints: 5
                min-endpoints: 1000
            autoreleaseAfter: 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Migrating from SDK2 to SDK3 API https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/project-docs/migrating-sdk-code-to-3.n.html
The autoreleaseAfter  was removed.
For maxEndpoints try to use IoConfig.maxHttpConnections

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30591215)